# Allowed file formats in email to case attachments

Tags: email2case

Is there any specific allowed file formats on email to case...Can users have any kind of attachments while sending email to case. for example: .exe files,.mov,.avi..

Does Salesforce restrict certain file types on the email attachments while using email to case.. Is this configurable?

I can see the File Upload and Download security options under setup; Does this configuration control  the email to case attachments as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on file types for email attachments. Any binary file will be accepted. There are file size restrictions, 25MB including including header, message, and attachments.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005026&language=en_US

Email-to-Case will enforce validation rules. You can use these to enforce specific file attachment types.